# slick-carousel scss is not working properly with react-slick using webpack as a bundler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-slick

When i use a cdn for slick-carousel it works fine but when i download it form npm and import it like :-

https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/669

It doesn't work.

Some how it works because of this:-

https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader

**But still not displaying the images ( css problem )**

**How to import slick-carousel so that is doen't break and works exactly like it works with a cdn.**